# AppendChild not creating new Divs, is my logic correct?

Tags: javascript

I created a js script that will create new divs as it iterates through the DB. I am wondering why one div is created, but no additional divs are created. Is there something wrong with my logic here, if not it's likely my html grid. There are 4 iterations of HERA 2.0 in the DB that the for loop is going through, but only one shows on the frontend.

```js
 function appendData(data) {
            var mainContainer = document.getElementById("myData");
            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                if (data[i].productName === "HERA 2.0") {
                    var div = document.createElement("div");
                    price.innerHTML = data[i].productPrice;
                    productTitle.innerHTML = data[i].productName;
                    images.src = 'https://' + data[i].productImage;
                    //div.innerHTML = 'Name: ' + data[i].productName + ' ' + data[i].productPrice;
                    mainContainer.appendChild(div);
                }
            }
```

This is what the HTML looks like:

```html
<div id="myData">
  <div class="container page-wrapper">
    <div class="page-inner">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="el-wrapper">
          <div class="box-up">
            <img id="images" src="">
            <div class="img-info">
              <div class="info-inner">
                <span id="productTitle"></span>
                <span class="p-company">Viasweat</span>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="box-down">
            <div class="h-bg">
              <div class="h-bg-inner"></div>
            </div>

            <a class="cart" id="cart" href="" target="_blank">
              <span class="price" id="price"></span>
              <span class="add-to-cart">
              <span class="txt">I want it!</span>
            </span>
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Edit - Dhruvi -

I've updated the code, and I get the same item being cloned. I think the append in the loop might be causing this.

```js
 function appendData(data) {
          var mainContainer = document.getElementById("myData");
          for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            if (data[i].productName === "HERA 2.0") {
              var div = document.querySelector("#row").cloneNode(true);
              price.innerHTML = data[i].productPrice;
              productTitle.innerHTML = data[i].productName;
              images.src = 'https://' + data[i].productImage;
              cart.href = data[i].productUrl;
              mainContainer.appendChild(div);
              console.log('div appended');
            }
          }
        }
        let data=[];
        appendData(data);
```

Comment: Maybe `if (data[i].productName === "HERA 2.0") {` is only fulfilled for one such element

Comment: Can you please paste enough data for debugging, currently the data is not sufficient.

Comment: I've added HTML

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please find the below solution.

You are always referring same price, productTitle, and image which is overriding your existing data. you have to refer newly created div's price, productTitle, and image.

```js
function appendData(data) {
  var mainContainer = document.getElementById("myData");
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    if (data[i].productName === "HERA 2.0") {
      var div = document.querySelector("div[data-selector='row']").cloneNode(true);
      price.innerHTML = data[i].productPrice;
      productTitle.innerHTML = data[i].productName;
      images.src = "https://" + data[i].productImage;
      cart.href = data[i].productUrl;
      mainContainer.appendChild(div)
      console.log("div appended!!!");
    }
  }
}
let data = [
  {
    productName: 'HERA 2.0',
    productPrice: 1,
    productImage: 'xyz',
    productUrl: 'xyz',
  },
  {
    productName: 'HERA 2.0',
    productPrice: 2,
    productImage: 'xyz',
    productUrl: 'xyz',
  },
  {
    productName: 'HERA 2.0',
    productPrice: 2,
    productImage: 'xyz',
    productUrl: 'xyz',
  },
  {
    productName: 'HERA 3.0',
    productPrice: 4,
    productImage: 'xyz',
    productUrl: 'xyz',
  }
];

appendData(data);
```

```html
<div id="myData">
  <div class="container page-wrapper">
    <div class="page-inner">
      <div class="row" data-selector="row">
        <div class="el-wrapper">
          <div class="box-up">
            <img id="images" src="">
            <div class="img-info">
              <div class="info-inner">
                <span id="productTitle"></span>
                <span class="p-company">Viasweat</span>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="box-down">
            <div class="h-bg">
              <div class="h-bg-inner"></div>
            </div>

            <a class="cart" id="cart" href="" target="_blank">
              <span class="price" id="price"></span>
              <span class="add-to-cart">
                <span class="txt">I want it!</span>
              </span>
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you Dhruvi. When I use this code, I get the same data being copied. Am I missing something with the clone node part?(added edit to post)

Comment: You are giving row as an id instead of class in querySelector.`document.querySelector("#row").cloneNode(true)` replace it with `document.querySelector(".row").cloneNode(true)`

Comment: please refer [this](https://codepen.io/makD/pen/rNLvovG) if you are still facing any issue.

Comment: The challenge for me with using .row (class) is that I get an undefined reference error. So I used the ID, but I think that breaks the loop and overwrites the data.

Comment: of course. Because there should be a unique id and not repetitive like class. You can explicitly remove id in function appendData.

Comment: I did, and the function stops working because of undefined reference error. Sorry for sounding so dumb, but if I can't reference it by classname, what should I do instead?

Comment: How about replacing the class/id selector with the data attribute. Please see the edited solution.

Comment: It's the same error. However, I replaced it with div.row and it worked, but I'm getting the same problem as I did when I used an #id. I get 4 clones created, but they are the same item (i.e. overwriting each other)

Answer (score 0):

```js
     function appendData(data) {
        var mainContainer = document.getElementById("myData");
        var price = document.getElementById("#price");
        var productTitle = document.getElementById("#productTitle");
        var image = document.getElementById("#images");
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            if (data[i].productName == "HERA 2.0") {
                var div = document.createElement("div");
                price.innerHTML = data[i].productPrice;
                productTitle.innerHTML = data[i].productName;
                images.src = 'https://' + data[i].productImage;
                //div.innerHTML = 'Name: ' + data[i].productName + ' ' + data[i].productPrice;
                mainContainer.appendChild(div);
            }
        }
    }
```

You should also check the argument when you pass data into `appendData()` and check if your json `productName` is correct or not. Based on the code above, I think it would work.

And if this is difficult, I think it'll be easier if you use `jQuery append`.